# How to Automate Google maps API using Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I want to be able to create  a test case in robot framework where i can open maps and locate the marker,
locate pick up and drop locations, vehicle moving and waypoints etc.
Is there any library in robot framework which will allow me to do so?
Thanks

Comment: You can use selenium library to extract details out of web page. Though automating google maps will be tricky.

Comment: Thank you but even using selenium library i cant get the marker details as there is no id for it.